# Динамическое создание кнопок в цикле - неправильно присваивается onclick

Tags: jquery

Мне необходимо динамически создать несколько кнопок с присваиванием каждой каких то атрибутов и навешивания onclick. Почему то все кнопки получают событие последней, а не свое собственное. Где я лажанулся и как решить проблему?

```
var buttons = {
"yes": {title: "Да", onclick: function(){alert('Да')} }, 
"no": {title: "Нет", onclick: function(){alert('Нет')}}
};

for(key in buttons)
{
let button = $("<button />").attr("name", key).html(buttons[key].title);
$("body").prepend(button);


$(button).on("click", function()
{
    buttons[key].onclick();
});
}
```

Comment: Сделайте `let key`, как вариант

Comment: Бинго! спасибо! А почему моя данная логика сработала неверно, интересно?

Comment: На здоровье. Остальные варианты есть в связанном вопросе

Comment: _"А почему моя данная логика сработала неверно"_ - потому что к моменту (асинхронного) вызова обработчика события `key` указывает на последний ключ объекта. Более подробно можно прочитать в том вопросе

Comment: Все понял! Еще раз спасибо!